# xdebug + netbeans + virtual host + WAMP (waiting for connection)

Tags: php, netbeans, wamp, xdebug

I'm trying to setup Netbeans to use xdebug for the umpteenth time and no matter what PC I do it on OR configuration OR online resource I try, I get the infamous "Waiting for connection".

I have switched my AV & windows firewall off.

I do see that when I do a netstat tho i'm not getting a port binding to 127.0.0.1 so not sure if this is the problem and how to solve it? Even if I add xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1 to my php.ini the 9000 port is still bound to 0.0.0.0

WAMP is in offline mode.

Netbeans -> PHP -> Debugging:

```
Debugger Port: 9000
Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
```

php.ini (I ran the http://xdebug.org/wizard.php and was told to DL the below DLL):

```
zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.5
vc11-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "E:\wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

netstat:

```
netstat -an | grep 9000
TCP    0.0.0.0:9000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:9000              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Comment: just a guess: you have tried to use the 32bit version instead of the 64bit? and try the nts one ... i do not use netbeans anymore, but my zend server does not like the 64bit not nts version, so i could be worth a try.

Comment: second tip: you read this: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host and this http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back

Comment: Nope I tried the different versions... ive read and read and read and just cant figure it out

Comment: WAMPServer comes with XDEBUG pre installed. The php.ini has it configured ( its at the bottom of the php.ini file ) and the XDEBUG DLL lives in the `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\zend_ext` folder. You may now have configured it twice, so remove your attempt and use the one that comes with the vanilla install.

Comment: Ye I know it comes "pre installed" but my problem is NetBeans is stuck on "Waiting for connection"